# Connection between Windows 7 and Windows 8

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, windows-8

I need to connect my Windows 7 and Windows 8 computer without any routers or anything similar. Of course I have a ethernet cable, I can use.

How can I achieve this?

It is for my exam to prevent depending on the school's network, as they have said, they are going to make service on the network that day

Comment: What are you trying to prevent exactly?

Comment: I am trying to prevent dependence of the school's network. And as I take 2 computers with me to the exam, I don't want to take a router with me too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect two computers to each other via their Ethernet ports using an [Ethernet crossover cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable). If your computer hardware/Ethernet card is recent, you most likely have auto-sensing Ethernet ports and can attempt to connect them using the straight Ethernet cable.

You will need to manually assign IP addresses to both computers from within network settings. Give one 192.168.1.1 and the other 192.168.1.2 both with subnet mask 255.255.255.0

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that solution, but I was thinking, if I could setup a simple DHCP-server, so I don't need to setup the IP-addresses

Comment: @The87Boy - Just do it manually since it takes more effort to install and configure a DHCP-server.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a Crossover network cable. ([such as this](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/1x-10m-Cat-6-Cat6-Crossover-Yellow-Premium-Ethernet-Network-LAN-Patch-Cable-Lead-/320848840105?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_15&hash=item4ab414c5a9&_uhb=1#ht_4462wt_1139)) Then you can [setup both computers](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-AU/windows-vista/Connect-two-computers-using-a-crossover-cable) to communicate directly.

A crossover cable is basically a network cable wired differently to allow the direct communication.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that solution, but I was thinking, if I could setup a simple DHCP-server, so I don't need to setup the IP-addresses

Comment: AFAIK, there's no "simple DHCP-server". Setting up the IP's isn't tricky or time consuming.

Comment: Okay, then it must be that solution